# What is the use of $setviewvalue and $render in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Can anybody explain me what is the use of $setViewValue and $render in AngularJs.

I don't see any use of these two services along with ng-Model.
Whenever i am changing my ng-model property, every attached view items are updating correctly and $render service i am using for rollback purpose.
What is the use of $setViewValue.

Thanks in Advance.